# Is there any way to get string consists of all the prints by a function

Tags: python

consider following method in a class

```
def printlist(self):
    traverser = self.head
    while traverser.next:
        print(traverser.val, end=", ")
        traverser = traverser.next
    else:
        print(traverser.val)
```

this method is returning None but printing something (like 1, 2, 3)
. My goal is to get as string which is printed by printlist method so that it could be used to return string representation of object as follows

```
def __str__(self):
   str_output = some_magic(self.printlist())
   return str_output
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have printList return a list and use the " ".join() method to print it. Consider what you're doing and if it makes sense

Comment: I could do that, but it is not solution to what  I really asked

Answer (score 0):

Currently your function is expected to do two things: find the values and construct (and print) the string. Functions should try and do one thing.

Use two separate functions.

For the values just use recursion:

```
def list_values(traverser):
    # yield all values from the linked list
    yield traverser.val
    if traverser.next:
        yield from list_values(traverser.next)
```

For constructing the string there is a built-in:

```
expected = ', '.join(some_magic(traverser))
```